# Approach for long running REST API

Tags: c#, rest, message-queue

We are trying to Consume REST API, for message processor which has some operation which might take more than configured timeout.

Would like to know, if the timeout of Http call to API, will stop execution of API, or API will keep executing?

Idea is that, we can fire and forget API, we are not worried if API does not return 404 or 503. But would like to hear if API will continue to execute?

Any input or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: use websocket instead?

Comment: Sounds like you need an asynchronous process. This is often accomplished by firing off a bus message to kick off the process. Your consumer sees the message on the queue and processes it. When it’s done it can fire another bus message to indicate it’s done, or call back to the website or update a database with the result etc. By following this process, your site doesn’t have to wait on the long running process in the HTTP call, and you free that thread up for other work.

Comment: Comments imply you are in control of API server.  Are you just a consumer or have control of the API server as well?  -> In case you are just consumer, it depends on the server implementation.

Comment: Yes.. we area actually using windows service and processing message, but message processing involves calling API, which is long running. We need not have to wait API to complete and come back in Message processor,  however wanted to understand if API will complete all operations even after timeout on Caller message processor..? And will it be good way of doing?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of background processing to handle the process.
I recommend using Hangfire for it.
https://www.hangfire.io/
Use Hangfire to enqueue a job, it will return a job id. You can return this job id to client side.
Expose another API to check for the status of this job.

Answer (score 0):

Great way is to handle this with callback/observer pattern. First of all, understand that there are two types of timeout, server and client. You can explicitly specify client timeout, server timeout is handled by server itself. 
So, you will need to implement algorithm such that,

1. you identify each request unique way and mark it before firing into
   memory or file/db.
2. Fire request with associated callback method.
   Hence on response you have control to do stuff like, mark request
   fulfilled or failed or what ever it is.
3. Mark/delete request data.